# How to access the assembly editor from C64 BASIC

Tags: assembly, editor, basic, c64

I was wondering about how to get into the assembly editor on the Commodore 64. Do you type in a command?

I have seen it being done on YouTube but it happens so fast that I can't keep up!

Comment: You may get better answers on http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you are using VICE emulator, press ALT+H

Answer (score 7):

The Commodore 64 does not have an assembler in the standard ROMs, (more's the pity; it would have been really handy).

But if you have a Commodore 128, then from BASIC 7.0 you can get into the monitor by typing `monitor` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There are third party cartridges for the Commodore 64 that provide an assembly language monitor. These are all different, and the way to invoke the monitor varies from cartridge to cartridge. Here are some examples:

- Final Cartridge 3, press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- SuperMon 64, type `SYS 49152`
- TEDMON, type `SYS1024` or `MONITOR`

Comment: Action Replay MK6 and compatible cardrigdes: type `mon` + return key.